# Track how many times each link on a page is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a loop that echos a list of links pulled from a database but I would like to track how many times each link listed is click.

form

```
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
```

to

```
link1 (2)
link2 (7)
link3 (3)
link4 (4)
link5 (1)
```

So, each time link 1 is clicked, the amount of times that link 1 is clicked should be recorded and displayed next to the link.

This is the code I have so far.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
//echo "<tr><td>" . $row['title'] . "</td><td>" . $row['url'] . "</td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td> <a href='" . $row['url'] . "' ' target='_blank'>" . $row['title'] . "</a> </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: First you have to keep track of the link clicks.  How do you do that? No point trying to display them if you don't keep track of them.

Comment: You don't have any code that even attempts to do what you want. All you have is some code that renders links. From your description it is not clear, how you want to persist the click information and when you want it to be shown (same user, different users, ect)

Comment: I just want that number to update every time the link is click. It should be the same with any user. Nothing fancy. I was hoping it would straight forward. I just need the logic for the code.

Comment: Then I would add another column to your database table with the link "Clicked", default set to `0`. When rendering out those URLs I would attach an `event listener` to listen for the `click` event to trigger a function that will then use `ajax` to post to a `php` file with the `URL` or an `ID` so you can `+1` to that record. Then once the `ajax` is complete you can redirect the client to the URL/link clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function for managing all clics

```js
var counter = {};

function manageClicks(url) {
 if (! counter[url]) counter[url] = 0;
 counter[url] ++;
 alert('you clicked '+counter[url]+' '+url);
 
    // return location.href = url;
 return false;
}
```

```html
<p>
Click some link:
</p>
<a href="#" onclick='manageClicks("url1")'> url1 </a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="manageClicks('url2')"> url2 </a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="manageClicks('url3')"> url3 </a><br>
```

Comment: But once the client reloads or is redirected no record is kept. So this isn't really keeping a record, it's just keeping a temporary log of what that individual client has click while on that page. This is a very bad solution.

Comment: How would I move it from that dialog to the page. I think Ill use this.

Comment: Also, i need to store it to a database. Any hints there?

Comment: @KirkBrown You are aware that using this when you close or reload the page the click count will be back to 0 again...

Comment: If you need to store in your database the number of click for each link, the links/url must call a php function (instead of a javascript one). Same principle.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to save it persistently. This is just an basic idea with a little bit of code. I did **not** test it.

Also you need a mapping to your link and the unique id to get the right cell in your database.

**The frontend stuff:**

```
<a href="http://yoururl.com/" onclick="handleLinkClick(this, 'a-unique-id')">
    Your link <span class="counter">(<?php echo getLogCount('a-unique-id') ?></span>)
</a>
```

Now if a user clicks the link you could do this:

```
function handleLinkClick(element, urlId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/logurl.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
           id: urlId
        }
    });

    // Count up immediately. You could also wait for a valid response. 
    var counterEl = element.querySelector('.counter');
    var currentCount = parseInt(counterElement.innerHTML);

    counterEl.innerHTML = (currentCount + 1).toString();
}
```

---

**The backend stuff:**

For the "getLogCount" you could define a function, which returns the clicks from your database (with PHP):

```
function getLogCount($urlId) {
    $result = 0;

    // @todo: Request to the database and get the count of the "$urlId".
    // And save the result it in "$result"

    return $result;
}
```

Now to log the click of the user in the database your "logurl.php" file could look like this:

```
$urlId = intval($_POST['id']);

// @todo: Update/Create a new entry in the database for the urlId.
// Maybe the columns could look something like: urlId (unique), clicks
```

---

I hope this will help you a little bit with your problem.